# Cannot play any type of video in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, video

My problem is, I cannot play any video in Firefox. In Chrome it works well. This is my HTML code fro embeding video:

```
<video id="video" controls="controls" width="600" height="357" poster="./static/img/video-thumb.png" preload="metadata" aria-describedby="full-descript">
   <source src="./static/video/demo.ogv" type="video/ogg; codecs=&quot;theora, vorbis&quot;">
   <source src="./static/video/demo.webm" type="video/webm">
   <source src="./static/video/demo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

When I try to access to (for example MP4 file), strange characters appear and no video. What is wrong with Firefox?

Paths are good, videos work

In my firefox console:

```
HTTP "Content-Type" of "text/html" is not supported. Load of media resource http://localhost:8104/home/static/video/demo.ogv failed.
HTTP "Content-Type" of "text/html" is not supported. Load of media resource http://localhost:8104/home/static/video/demo.webm failed.
HTTP "Content-Type" of "text/html" is not supported. Load of media resource http://localhost:8104/home/static/video/demo.mp4 failed.
```

Comment: Your server is telling the browser that the video is an HTML document. Fix that.

Comment: Yea, I know (its wrote right there), but how can I fix it? I have no idea.

Comment: Step 1: Find out what HTTP server you are using.

Comment: Probably apache on linux, but I don't really know, I am just one of developers from company and I haven't got permissions to access server configuration.

Comment: You *must* fix the server configuration. If you don't have access, either get access or pass the bug ticket to someone who does.

Answer (score 4):

Your server is delivering everything with a

**"Content-Type" of "text/html"**

Assuming it is an apache server you need to add the following .htaccess file into the directory that contains the video.

```
# Server can play audio
# MP3 audio
AddType audio/mpeg3 .mp3
AddType audio/mp3 .mp3
AddType audio/x-mpeg3 .mp3

# Ogg Vorbis audio
AddType audio/ogg .ogg
AddType audio/ogg .oga

# Server can play video
# Ogg Theora video
AddType video/ogg .ogv

# MP4 video
AddType video/mp4 .mp4

# Webm video
AddType video/webm .webm
```

For other servers you need to check the documentation on how to set the MIME type.

Comment: Does the host / server you are using allow you to run php? If it does you could use PHP to deliever the files with the correct http header information.

Comment: No, we are using Java. I contacted colleague, who has access to server configuration.

Comment: Just in case firefox might work with the wrong mimi types .... did you try removing ... type="video/mp4" ... from the HTML?

Comment: @LeoGallucci Probably yes, but not me. Someone who owns the server fixed it but idk how. Anyway I'm out of that project for more than 1.5 year, so I cannot access to it anymore.

Answer (score -3):

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation that's why posting here.
So i am facing the same problem so what i did is i take the audio path from the host and

```
<a href="http:// Your path" target="_blank"> Click to play Audio </a>
```

So it will open in new page and easily will play your audio.

Comment: This is what Asker tried already in the question (see their code).